# How does one combine two uneven dataframes to create a full species matrix for analysis?

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create **one large** **dataframe** from two smaller dataframes with the first three columns in common between each small dataframe. I also want shared species between the two columns to fall into the same columns.

My dataframe (df) 1 has 38obs. of 40 variables

My dataframe (df) 2 has 30obs. of 35 variables

I want to retain these headers common to both (LOGID, DECAY, DIAMETER). Some species are common to both dataframes and others are unique to one or the other. I want all species occurrences in a new table.

Do I use cbind with some sort of match function? or create dummy columns? How would I go about this?

e.g. DF1:

```
LOGID DECAY DIAMETER SP1 SP2 SP3
1       2      20     2   2   3 
2       4      22     1   0   7
3       4      12     3   1   2
```

e.g. DF2

```
LOGID DECAY DIAMETER SP1 SP5 SP3 SP7
4       2      25     8   0   2   1
5       4      10     0   0   3   1
6       2      11     1   1   1   1
```

I want them like this:

```
LOGID DECAY DIAMETER SP1 SP2 SP3 SP5 SP7
1       2      20     2   2   3   0   0  
2       4      22     1   0   7   0   0   
3       4      12     3   1   2   0   0  
4       2      25     8   0   2   0   1   
5       4      10     0   0   3   0   1  
6       2      11     1   0   1   1   1
```

I have tried using the code suggested below and end up with the following problem mainly because I didnt specify what I wanted the first time..... I want common species to fall into shared columns.

```
LOGID DECAY DIAMETER SP1x SP2 SP3x SP1y SP5 SP3y SP7
1       2      20     2    2    3    0   0   0   0
2       4      22     1    0    7    0   0   0   0
3       4      12     3    1    2    0   0   0   0
4       2      25     0    0    0    8   0   2   1
5       4      10     0    0    0    0   0   3   1
6       2      11     0    0    0    1   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps (but you are asked to produce a small example in code so we can test before throwing out code.):

```
 merge(df1,df2, by=1:3, all=TRUE)
```

With your example data, my suggestion produces:

```
> merge(DF1,DF2, by=1:3, all=TRUE)
  LOGID DECAY DIAMETER SP1 SP2 SP3 SP4 SP5 SP6 SP7
1     1     2       20   2   2   3  NA  NA  NA  NA
2     2     4       22   1   0   7  NA  NA  NA  NA
3     3     4       12   3   1   2  NA  NA  NA  NA
4     4     2       25  NA  NA  NA   8   0   2   1
5     5     4       10  NA  NA  NA   0   0   3   1
6     6     2       11  NA  NA  NA   1   1   1   1
```

If you want to convert the NA's to 0's (which I see as not really true) then just do it:

```
> DF3 <- merge(DF1,DF2, by=1:3, all=TRUE)
> DF3[is.na(DF3)] <- 0
> DF3
  LOGID DECAY DIAMETER SP1 SP2 SP3 SP4 SP5 SP6 SP7
1     1     2       20   2   2   3   0   0   0   0
2     2     4       22   1   0   7   0   0   0   0
3     3     4       12   3   1   2   0   0   0   0
4     4     2       25   0   0   0   8   0   2   1
5     5     4       10   0   0   0   0   0   3   1
6     6     2       11   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
```

If you really do not have any "overlapping" values in the shared columns and only want to "rbind" the dataframes then there is an `rbind.fill` function in pkg:plyr. With the new example:

```
library( plyr )
rbind.fill(DF1,DF2)
  LOGID DECAY DIAMETER SP1 SP2 SP3 SP5 SP7
1     1     2       20   2   2   3  NA  NA
2     2     4       22   1   0   7  NA  NA
3     3     4       12   3   1   2  NA  NA
4     4     2       25   8  NA   2   0   1
5     5     4       10   0  NA   3   0   1
6     6     2       11   1  NA   1   1   1
```

Comment: And it will pay to study help("merge") to understand how duplicate column names are handled, how NAs are introduced, and so on.

Comment: I guess I was assuming these were in a "normal form" such as might be produced by `as.data.frame.table`.

Comment: yes I would agree based on the original question. I guess my comment is more directed at @Gnatz2meetu. `merge` sometimes takes a bit of work to tune and understand.

Comment: Thanks @vpipkt, The problem is that really I want to rbind but somehow have the species unique to df 1 appear as zeros in df 2. A bit like on https://amywhiteheadresearch.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/combining-dataframes-when-the-columns-dont-match/comment-page-1/#comment-1719

Comment: Thanks for the answer @BondedDust but maybe you or someone else could elaborate on the code a little based on the code I have added? or improve the answer?

Comment: I think the answer was spot on. You will notice that the linked example had NA's.

Comment: @BondedDust Sorry but I accepted your answer too quickly, when I performed my dataframe merge I ended up with repeated species names in the headers e.g. Bradysia sp. 1.x, Bradysia sp. 2.y etc. Please help!

Comment: As always.... edit your example so it has the desired level of complexity and specify what is a "correct" answer.

Comment: @BondedDust Apologies for that, I have updated the question matey :) I will accept if you can do what I'm looking for. Agaian I am very appreciative!

Answer (score 2):

First `cbind` the extra columns to the two data frames. For example:

```
df1 <- cbind(df1, numeric(nrow(df1)),numeric(nrow(df1)),numeric(nrow(df1)),numeric(nrow(df1)))
names(df1)[7:10] = c("SP4","SP5","SP6","SP7")
```

Then do likewise for the second data frame.

Then you can `rbind` the two data frames.

If there are one or two  variables present in both data frames, consider combining them in the `rbind`ed data frame like so:

```
df.combined $SP3<-  df.combined $SP3.x + df.combined $SP3.y
```

You will want to examine this case quite carefully before dropping  `SP3.x` and `SP3.y`

You may also reconsider `merge`, including the shared variables in the `by` argument.  But only if you are certain the variables present on the two original date frames will not collide. Otherwise you will have duplicate logid and decay tuples.

All this begs the question if you would be better off to try something like `unstack` or `melt` considering species as a variable. This would be more advantageous if you have several variables present in both data frames.  Basically flatten your two original data frames, row bind them, then tabulate out the species variable as columns.

Comment: Having a problem mate, the above answer almost worked except as you alluded to, there are duplicate columns now which I missed.....e.g. Bradysia sp. 1.x, Bradysia sp. 1.y. I would like commonalities between two dataframes merged too!

Comment: Cheers @vpipkt!!! I'll upvote you whe I get my old account mergewd with my new one

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many ways to do this I have found.
I appreciate all comments above!

Here is how I eventually did it:

Because my matrices are very large with many species, trying to find the common species can also be done using intersect: `common.species <- intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))`

Then change to a dataframe: `common.species=as.data.frame(common.species)`

Merge your two dataframes: `Datamerged<-merge(df1,df2, by=common.species, all=TRUE)`

Change the NAs to zeros: `Datamerged[is.na(Datamerged)] <- 0`

Voila!